# Rename root module in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, module

How to rename root module in android studio? I have tried (right click the module then click refactor then click rename) but I got warning "can't rename root module"

Answer (score 100):

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search my current root module name and found the name to be in the `settings.gradle` file as `rootProject.name=...`. I renamed it and synced the project (File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files) and the root module name was updated.

Answer (score 21):

In root of your project
open setting.gradle and change
rootProject.name='YOUR NEW NAME'

then close and restart android studio

Comment: This is the [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60087611/3025856) that @Tarasantan four months ago. Please be sure to read existing answers prior to contributing a new one.

Comment: Instead of closing and reopening AS, you can sync the project (File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files).

Answer (score 4):

Close the project.  (File > Close)

Rename the root folder of the project.

At the welcome screen "Open an existing Android Studio project" and provide the new path.

> On your link that's the second answer or [see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050557/how-to-rename-a-project-in-android-studio).

Answer (score 4):

This is tested for a pure Java projects (without any C/C++ code):

- close the project and make a copy of the folder containing it
- rename the new copied folder to reflect new project name
- delete all *.iml files
- reopen the project: Android Studio will resync Gradle, rebuild iml files
- review the modules.xml file to remove reference to old project name
- new project renamed works exactly as previous one: you can run the app without completely reinstalling it (all previous app data/settings/cache will be preserved)

Answer (score 4):

Video tutorial: https://youtu.be/7aQjiae2doU

1. Refactor the name to `com.example.[NewFileName]` in path:

   > app>java>com.example.[OldFileName]

---

2. Go to strings.xml and change code to `<string name="app_name”>[NewFileName]</string>` in path:

   > app>res>values>strings.xml

---

3. Go to build.gradle (Module: app) and change code to `applicationId "com.example.[NewFileName]”` in path:

   > Gradle Scripts>build.gradle (Module: app)

---

4. Go to settings.gradle (Project Settings) and change code to `rootProject.name='[NewFileName]'` in path:

   > Gradle Scripts>build.gradle (Project Settings)

---

5. Press `Sync now` prompt

---

6. Rename your folder to `[NewFileName]` outside Android Studio

---

7. Reopen your project and rebuild project in path:

   > Build>Rebuild Project

---

Answer (score 2):

In your Project pane, click on the little gear icon ( setting icon at the right top)

Uncheck / De-select the Compact Empty Middle Packages option

Your package directory will now be broken up in individual directories
Individually select each directory you want to rename, and:

Right-click it

Select Refactor

Click on Rename

In the Pop-up dialog, click on Rename Package instead of Rename Directory

Enter the new name and hit Refactor

Allow a minute to let Android Studio update all changes

Note: When renaming com in Android Studio, it might give a warning. In such case, select Rename All

Comment: Thanks I can rename the package name with your good solution, but I cannot rename the root module. When I renamed it, I got warning "can't rename root mdule".

I have tried this soution :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568715/android-studio-project-root-directory-name-change-project-name-change

but when I imported the project, the root module name, back to the origin name.

Answer (score 1):

**Change in settings.gradle**

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        }
    }
    
    rootProject.name = "project_name" // change this 
    
    include ':app'
```