# Installation failed with message Invalid File

Tags: android, android-studio, android-build

> Installation failed with message Invalid File:
>   K:\project\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\with_ImageProcessor\debug\slices\slice_0.apk.
>   It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing
>   version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

i am running my project in android studio 2.3 beta 3 .

Comment: just uninstall previous version of app and reinstall

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532044/how-to-solve-installation-failed-due-to-invalid-apk-file

Comment: Go to the device's Settings->Apps, check if your app is showing in the list. I assume it is installed for some different profile not for your active profile. You need to uninstall it for all the profiles

Comment: @Bharat : Does it solve your issue?

Comment: it was not working on any device I try htcone,lg,s4

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run > Un-check (Enable Instant Run to hot swap code)

Comment: In my case, it was an apostrophe in the path to the project that disrupted building. Setting up my project anew and removing any special characters from the path solved the issue.

Comment: Follow these steps. Go to Settings
Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run => Uncheck: Enable Instant Run....

Comment: I seem to be having this problem and none of the suggested solutions work since I upgraded to Android Studio 3.5.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I found the solution go to

> settings>build,execute,deployment>instant run>Enable instant run to
>   hot swap code /resource change on deploy(unchecked this option)

`

Comment: Works on android studio 3.0 as well

Comment: so do you want us to disable instant run?

Comment: you can try with: Build-->Clean Project; Build-->Make Project; and then run your apk in your device.

Comment: This option is not exists for me, but restarting android studio worked

Answer (score 424):

Click **Build** tab ---> **Clean Project**

Click **Build** tab ---> **Build APK**

Run.

Comment: yes similar issue happens for Xcode too, you also need clean frequently and build

Comment: Although it worked, but I was wondering why 'Clean Project' is really required ?

Comment: If this code doesn't work then uncheck 'Instant Run' and try again.

Answer (score 78):

Just follow two steps

Step 1 : Build---> Clean

Step 2 : Build--> Build APK

Hope it works. Good luck guys

Comment: why is this not automatically set?

Answer (score 26):

I solved it this way:

Click Build tab ---> Clean Project

Click Build tab ---> Rebuild Project

Click Build tab ---> Build APK

Run.

Answer (score 24):

Hopefully, this should solve your problem.

Do follow the following steps.

**1. Clean your Project**

[image: Cleaning the project]

**2. Rebuild your project**

[image: Rebuilding the project]

**3. Finally Build and Run your project**

Answer (score 15):

First, as already mentioned, try cleaning and rebuilding the project. If that does not work for you, try this:

**Settings** > **Build, Execution, Deployment**:
  Un-check **Enable Instant Run to hot swap code...**

This solved the problem right away for me.

P.S. I posted this answer since it's 2017 and I don't think this feature existed in 2014, so it wouldn't cause this problem.

Answer (score 15):

Please follow the below steps
File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run > Un-check (Enable Instant Run to hot swap code)

this is working for me

thanks

Answer (score 12):

This happened with me when I copied a project code from one laptop to another one and tried running the project. What fixed this for me was:

1. Delete the project's **build** folder
2. **Clean** Project
3. **Build** project
4. Run

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I had the same issue when the name of my project contains a "&" sign.The solution is to rename the project name,from file browser, so it doesn't contain any "&" signs and then from:

- **Build menu-> Clean Project**
- **Build menu-> Build APK**

I've tested it two times and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 5):

For me it's:

Click Build tab ---> 
Clean Project

Rebuild Project

Build APK

Answer (score 5):

**follow some steps:**

```
Clean Project
Rebuild Project
Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

Now run your project. Hope it will work.

**It's work for me.**

Comment: `Invalidate Caches / Restart` was essential for me! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Work for me:

1. Delete these folders
2. Run app

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this in gradle project 
`dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3' }`

Answer (score 1):

In my case , there was a single qutation `'` in project directory and after removing it resolved

Comment: how did you locate it?

Comment: first open your project folder. if there is any quotation in address bar, try renaming that folder

Answer (score 1):

Delete the Intermediate folder after then run the project is working fine actually that APK builds to another system.
Go to app/build/intermediates.

Answer (score 1):

I found its work by restarting my phone :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Invalidate cache/restart
2. Clean Project
3. Rebuild Project
4. Run your app / Build APK

These steps are enough to solve most of the problems related to Gradle build in any way. These steps helped me solve this problem too.

Answer (score 1):

Just Invalidate Cache and Restart !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project and rebuild, if doesn't work try disabling the Instant Run from Settings>Build>Instant Run in case you are running someone else's code.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with my Android Studio install.

I am building out a new CI server and although I installed Android Studio and hooked up the SDK, etc., I did not open the studio with the project -- instead just went to the command line to build.  When I subsequently opened the project in the studio, it started prompting for all sorts of updates.  Followed the bouncing-ball and then I was able to reach my USB tethered device.

Hopefully, this is helpful for Build Master and DevOps as a "got-cha" to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here worked, I had to:

1. Close android studio
2. `rm -rf ./android/.idea`
3. Build -> Build Bundle/APK(s) -> Build APK(s)

Answer (score 0):

The path may be invalid, if Android Studio is pointing to the wrong version of the file. This can happen if you make gradle automatically rename your built APK, using [setProperty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332474/how-to-set-versionname-in-apk-filename-using-gradle), like:

```js
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company.app"
    versionName "1.2.0"
    // Rename the built apk file
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", "MyApp-$versionName")
    ...
}
```

Sometimes, an updated `versionName` is not properly "refreshed" to Android Studio, so it can point to an old versionName in the file name. In this case, just do a Gradle sync then Build, to ensure the `versionName` matches the built file path. Gradle sync is either:

- Android Studio 4.x ➔ Toolbar at the far right ➔ Press the 'elephant + down arrow' icon, which has the tooltip **"Sync Project with Gradle Files"** ➔ <kbd>Build</kbd> ➔ Make Project

[image: Android Studio toolbar - Button: Sync Project with Gradle Files]

- Android Studio 4.x ➔ <kbd>Help</kbd> ➔ <kbd>Find Action</kbd> ➔ search for "sync" ➔ **"Sync Project with Gradle Files"** ➔ <kbd>Build</kbd> ➔ Make Project

Answer (score 0):

If none of those solutions work for you just close the Android Studio and open it. It worked for me on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was:

```
1 -> Build -> Clean Project.
2 -> Build -> Rebuild Project 
3 -> File -> Invalidate Caches and restart.
```