# In Android, what does the "Installation failed with message Invalid File" error mean?

Tags: android

I get this error when I open my app:

```
Installation failed with message Invalid File: C:\Users\wlgus\Desktop\Android\Asimplegame_ver4 (2)\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

I don't know what I can do to fix this error. I already download apk but it didn't work.

Comment: What were you doing when you got this error?

Comment: when i just open this app..

Comment: Do you mean your Android app on a device, the Android app in an emulator, or the Android Studio application?

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219784/installation-failed-with-message-invalid-file

Comment: I left a solution to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219784/installation-failed-with-message-invalid-file)

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42219784/8555823).

**Method 1 :** Try to clean, rebuild, and run the app.

If it doesn't work

**Method 2 :** settings>build,execute,deployment>instant run>Enable instant run to hot swap code /resource change on deploy(unchecked this option)

Answer (score 2):

This is likely because the debug key in android studio is different from the one you used to install the app previously.

Are you by any chance installing it from a different computer?

Comment: Thank u for answering. i will try it in other computer!!

Comment: It will only work on the computer you last installed it on. Any other computer will yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the `build` directory (`app/build`) and then re-building the project worked for me. Try this too, if previous answers fail to resolve the issue.