# problem when installing the apk file on my phone

Tags: android, apk

I am working with android studio and i have a problem when building and installing the apk in my phone , it give me this error :
installation failed with message invalid file :~/project/app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slices_1.apk it is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing

ps : i don't have any version of the apk on my phone

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219784/installation-failed-with-message-invalid-file)

Answer (score 0):

Some times apps installed for all users in the phone, if you don't find the app in your phone drawer, then go to Settings>apps and try to find, if you found one then uninstall it from there, then you'll be able to install the new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
To solve this problem, there's are some ways, you can try any one feasible to you:
1. You need to login to that user environment and uninstall the app.
2. Uninstall for all users(you need to be admin user) Go to Settings > Apps, find and 
open the app info. Then, open the overflow menu (3 vertical dots), and choose 
Uninstall for all users.
```