# Failed to open APK, Invalid file when running my dart code using visual studio

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, android-studio, dart

I'm unable to run my android emulator. I have already checked flutter doctor in cmd and no issues has been found.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.556], locale en-MY)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.66.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

However, it shows built failed with an exception as below

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     AAPT: error: failed to open APK: Invalid file.
```

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219784/installation-failed-with-message-invalid-file